# Scale matplotlib text artist to fill rectangle patch bounding box

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a rectangle patch and text artist in matplotlib, is it possible to scale the text such that it fills the rectangle as best as possible without overfilling on either dimension?

e.g.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=(0, 6), ylim=(0, 3))

x0, y0 = 1, 1
x1, y1 = 5, 1.5
width = x1 - x0
height = y1 - y0
    
rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((x0, y0), width, height, fc="none", ec="y")
ax.add_patch(rect)

text = ax.text(x0 + width / 2, y0 + height / 2, "yellow", ha="center", va="center")
```

Produces

[image]

I would like to programmatically rescale the text to fit within the rectangle (including descenders), akin to this result found using trial-and-error:

[image]

We can assume some simplifying constraints, namely that the figure size and axis limits are known and set ahead of time and don't need to change after this operation.

Comment: It's possible to get the text size and then imply the scaling of the font size. Also, using mono font would help, if it's an option for you. Would you like help with any of these options?

Comment: Alas, monospace font would be detrimental for the usecase here, although I can see how that would simplify it.

Comment: what about the first option?

Comment: It sounds like a reasonable approach but accounting for the descenders might get tricky?

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively simple to scale the text based on a comparison between its window extent and the window extent of the rectangle:

```
def rescale_text(rect, text):
    r = rect.get_window_extent()
    t = text.get_window_extent()
    scale = min(r.height / t.height, r.width / t.width)
    text.set_size(text.get_size() * scale)
```

[image]

However, it looks like the window extent height is computed based on the font, not the actual string. As a result, it properly handles descenders, but it continues to even when they're not present in the string, and it doesn't account for strings with all "short" characters, e.g.:

[image]

While this is probably passable for my application, if there were a way of getting the text extent tightened to what is actually being drawn, that would be ideal.

Comment: There might be some problems with this approach if the font size is small (close to 1) - I think matplotlib only allows integer font sizes, at least for mono. Otherwise, it should work.